# App migrated to UIKit lifecycle doesn't call SceneDelegate

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, uikit

We migrated our app from the SwiftUI to the UIKit lifecycle and app containment, creating a standard AppDelegate, SceneDelegate, and updating the required info.plist properties. I didn't follow this tutorial, but if you're unfamiliar, this is exactly what we did as well. https://mokacoding.com/blog/how-to-migrate-from-swiftui-to-uikit-life-cycle/.

Our issue is that physical iPhone devices that had the app with the SwiftUI lifecycle installed, black screens and are unresponsive on launch. Debugging proves that this is because the `SceneDelegate` setup functions are never called at all. iPhone simulators, building to Mac, etc, works fine.

Deleting the app and reinstalling resolves this problem, but we can't ask that from our installed base.

*Is there any way to force installed apps to clear their cache or whatever it is that controls launch configurations?*

Here is the relevant code.

**AppDelegate, this is being called**

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
    return true
}
```

**SceneDelegate, this is NOT being called**

```
func scene(_ scene: UIScene, willConnectTo session: UISceneSession, options connectionOptions: UIScene.ConnectionOptions) {
    guard let scene = scene as? UIWindowScene else { return }

    window = UIWindow(windowScene: scene)
    let viewController: UIViewController
    if isLoggedIn {
        viewController = MainViewController()
    } else {
        viewController = UIHostingController(
            rootView: LandingView().injectingEnvironment()
        )
    }
    window!.rootViewController = viewController
    window!.makeKeyAndVisible()
}
```

**info.plist**

```
<key>UIApplicationSceneManifest</key>
<dict>
    <key>UIApplicationSupportsMultipleScenes</key>
    <true/>
    <key>UISceneConfigurations</key>
    <dict>
        <key>UIWindowSceneSessionRoleApplication</key>
        <array>
            <dict>
                <key>UISceneConfigurationName</key>
                <string>Default Configuration</string>
                <key>UISceneDelegateClassName</key>
                <string>$(PRODUCT_MODULE_NAME).SceneDelegate</string>
            </dict>
        </array>
    </dict>
</dict>
```

Comment: If anyone also followed the article linked the question, do not turn off support multiple windows. It seems that disabling multiple windows prevents UIKit from launching a new scene when the previous scene is no longer available.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try to remove scene configurations manifest from `Info.plist` and create it programmatically in `AppDelegate`, like

```
class AppDelegate: NSObject, UIApplicationDelegate {


    func application(_ application: UIApplication, configurationForConnecting connectingSceneSession: UISceneSession, options: UIScene.ConnectionOptions) -> UISceneConfiguration {
        let configuration = UISceneConfiguration(name: nil, sessionRole: connectingSceneSession.role)
        if connectingSceneSession.role == .windowApplication {
            configuration.delegateClass = SceneDelegate.self
        }
        return configuration
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you so much sir, after restarting Xcode and what not, this was the only thing that fixed this shit of migrating from a SwiftUI lifecycle to UIKit's